# Pandas: Y Axis consistency across graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)

reso_names = [x[0] for x in resolution3]
reso_values = [x[1] for x in resolution3]

plt.bar(range(len(reso_values[60:130])), reso_values[60:130], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(reso_names[60:130])), list(reso_names[60:130]), rotation='vertical')

plt.margins(0.075)
plt.xlabel('Resolution Category Tier 3')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.title('Resolution Category Tier 3 Volume', {'family' : 'Arial Black',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 22})

plt.savefig('Reso3_A.pdf', format='pdf')
plt.show()

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)
plt.bar(range(len(reso_values[0:60])), reso_values[0:60], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(reso_names[0:60])), list(reso_names[0:60]), rotation='vertical')

plt.margins(0.075)
plt.xlabel('Resolution Category Tier 3')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.title('Resolution Category Tier 3 Volume', {'family' : 'Arial Black',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 22})

plt.savefig('Reso3_B.pdf', format='pdf')
plt.show()
```

I was told that I could use `sharey=True` to achieve having the same y-axis in both these graphs but I'm unsure as to where exactly to make the change.

Comment: Did you have a look into [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the y-limits explicitly

```
plt.ylim(min(reso_values), max(reso_values)+1)
```

before each call to `plt.savefig`.

---

To use `sharey`, you'd need to create a single figure containing two (or more) axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import string

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 130
reso_values = np.random.randint(10, size=N)
reso_names = np.random.choice(list(string.letters), N*4).view('|S{}'.format(4))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharey=True, figsize=(14,18), dpi=50)

mpl.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
fig.suptitle('Resolution Category Tier 3 Volume', 
          **{'family': 'Arial Black', 'size': 22, 'weight': 'bold'})

for ax, start, end in zip(axs, (0, 60), (60, N)):
    names, values = list(reso_names[start:end]), reso_values[start:end]
    ax.bar(range(len(values)), values, align='center')
    ax.set_xlabel('Resolution Category Tier 3')
    ax.set_ylabel('Volume')
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(names, rotation='vertical')
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(names))
# plt.savefig('Reso3.pdf', format='pdf')
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is make the y axis of the second graph the same as the y axis thats used for the first one ?

Comment: Could you just please explain how I can change the increments and if I need more than 2 subgraphs what should the code look like ?